# OpenSSL use -CAFile on LetsEncrypt-Certificate

Tags: ssl, tomcat8, confluence, lets-encrypt, plesk-onyx

I'm currently trying to set up a Confluence (6.6.0) on an Ubuntu Server with Plesk (17.5.3) and Let's-Encrypt-Extension installed.

Confluence itself is up and running, but I am experiencing some issues, when it comes to SSL. Securing the Domain itself is easily done by just taking the "easy road" via the Plesk-Panel One-Click-Installer.

The Certificates will be located at `/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/archive/<MY_DOMAIN>/`

There are four .pem-files in this directory:

- `cert1.pem`
- `chain1.pem`
- `fullchain1.pem`
- `privkey1.pem`

But now i need to tell Tomcat, that i have this certificate installed in the server.xml.
Since the Plesk-Let's-Encrypt-Extension saves the files as .pem-files i need to convert them via OpenSSL to be able to use the Java keytool.
I found a nice tutorial about this topic in general right here:
http://robblake.net/post/18945733710/using-a-pem-private-key-and-ssl-certificate-with

When i am trying the following, i get stuck at the very beginning, when i try to execute

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <PATH>/cert1.pem -inkey <PATH>/privkey1.pem -out foo.p12 -name tomcat -chain -CAFile <PATH>/chain1.pem
```

The command itself runs, when I am not using `-CAFile` and generates my .p12-File, but then throws a warning:

```
Error unable to get local issuer certificate getting chain.
```

If i try adding `-CAFile /usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/archive/<MY_DOMAIN>/chain1.pem` or using `[...]/fullchain1.pem` instead nothing will happen but OpenSSL printing the Usage-Documentation.

So since these four .pem-files are the only ones available i'm not sure what else to do.

Since i need the intermediate-certs too, i am wondering what i have to do here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The usage message is because the option is `-CAfile` (lowercase f) not `-CAFile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `chain1.pem` file from Let's Encrypt is incomplete. In my case it contains only one certificate - the intermediate CA *Let's Encrypt Authority X3*

Check the contents of this file. In my case there was only one certificate.

```
openssl x509 -noout -in chain1.pem -subject -issuer

subject= /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
issuer= /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
```

The reason for the error is that openssl misses the certificate for *DST Root CA X3*

How to create the complete chain.

1. Download the DST Root CA X3 certificate:

   ```
   wget http://apps.identrust.com/roots/dstrootcax3.p7c
   ```
2. Convert it to PEM

   ```
   openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in dstrootcax3.p7c -out dstrootcax3.pem -print_certs
   ```

   At this moment the certificate for DST Root CA X3 is in `dstrootcax3.pem`
3. Build full chain (overwrites `fullchain1.pem`)

   ```
   cp chain1.pem fullchain1.pem
   echo >> fullchain1.pem
   cat dstrootcax3.pem >> fullchain1.pem
   ```
4. Generate P12 file

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert1.pem -inkey privkey1.pem -chain -CAfile fullchain1.pem -out cert1.p12 -name tomcat
   ```

To check that all certificates are stored in P12 file:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -info -in cert1.p12
```

Good luck with the `keytool` ;)

Comment: Thank you :) This solution worked for me.
Nevertheless, i noticed that a don't even need to do this. The warning in Confluence came from a misconfiguration of nginx, that I run as reverse Proxy. So all the fancy SSL-Stuff is done on the Reverse-Proxy, and i simply have to set the Proxy in server.xml the right way. After i fixed that nginx-issue, the official documentation of Atlassian how to change the server.xml file worked... so keytool-stuff is luckily not needed :)...

Comment: There's no real need to include the root cert; neither TLS nor Java requires it, and OpenSSL doesn't require it if you just _omit_ `-chain` from `pkcs12 -export`